# How to use Oauth2 service accounts with Google Drive and the App Engine SDK

Tags: google-app-engine, sdk, oauth-2.0, google-drive-api

Accessing Google Drive with App Engine and service accounts works fine. To make it work, I also had to share my Drive files with the Service Account Name: appid@appspot.gserviceaccount.com.

But when I use the GAE SDK I receive a 401. I think the reason is the service_account name of the SDK for my shares. The service account name of the SDK  is: test@localhost according to :

```
app_identity.get_service_account_name()  # returns test@localhost
```

The error message in the SDK console :

An error occurred: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files/0B9-mE....................nM/children?alt=json&key=AI........................N0 returned "Invalid Credentials">

This is the code to access Google Drive :

```
def get(self):

    SCOPE = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    credentials = AppAssertionCredentials(scope=SCOPE)
    logging.info(app_identity.get_service_account_name())
    http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
    if os.environ['SERVER_SOFTWARE'].startswith('Development') : 
        service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http, developerKey='...API key...')
    else :
        service = build('drive', 'v2', http=http, developerKey='...APY key...')
    # drive requests
```

**UPDATE :**

My personal opinion : This can only work with GAE and not with the SDK, because I cannot make a Drive share with the SDK service_account name. Or is it possible to specify another service account name.

Answer (score 2):

Please check the documentation for [Application-owned service accounts](https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts), and there is also a [video you can watch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iK14bfd6qhs) too.

The docs contain Python sample code.

Comment: Did you understand my question? It works with GAE, but not with the GAE SDK. And I do not think it can work, because of the share.

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't understand. What is the difference between GAE and GAE SDK? If you mean GAE service accounts, that is not possible, because Drive Apps must be associated with a client ID.

Comment: SDK = development on my PC and with GAE I mean the deployed (in the cloud) app. So GAE works fine, but using the SDK it cannot work in this scenario because of the test@localhost service account name, which is used to access a drive dile.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts gives a 404 now. It would be better if this answer included all necessary information right here.